# Javascript.bind - ES5 Vs ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bind

How can I use bind in ES6?

In pre-es6 way of coding (I assume this is ES5), I would do:

```
var app = {};
app.log = function(req, res) {
    var respond = this.respond.bind(this, req, res);
    return respond(400, 'no data received');
}

app.respond = function(req, res, status, message) {
    console.log(req); // hello
    console.log(status); // 400
    console.log(message); // no data received
}

app.log('hello');
```

But how I can do that in ES6?

```
export default function log (req, res) {
    var respond = this.respond.bind(this, req, res);
    return respond(400, 'no data received');
}

function respond (req, res, status, message) {
    console.log(req); 
    console.log(status); 
    console.log(message); 
}
```

Of course I will get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'respond' of undefined
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `app` object in ES6 as well?

Comment: WTH do you use `bind` at all? Just do `this.respond(req, res, 400, 'no data received');` (and the equivalent ES6 solution presents itself)

Comment: I am trying to see how `bind` works. Saw it being used in other program that I have to use it as a reference so I am trying to understand why they use `bind` at all.

Comment: You have to use it when you want to reference a function that needs to be called as a method. You wouldn't have to use it on `app.respond`, which doesn't use `this`, nor on the plain `respond` which isn't a method at all. If you wanted to use it for partial application, use `.bind(null, …)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you have to use export in this case. Simply make a class.

```
class App {

    log(req, res) {
        var respond = this.respond.bind(this , req , res);
        return respond(400, 'no data received');
    }

    respond(req, res, status, message) {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(message);
    }

}

var app = new App();
app.log('hello');
```

Comment: Don't use `class`es for singletons. An object literal is usually more appropriate.

Comment: `Don't use classes for singletons. An object literal is usually more appropriate.` what do u mean?

Comment: @teelou: You use a class when you need to create multiple objects which all have the same functionality but hold different data. If you don't intend to create multiple objects, create a single one with an object literal, just like you did in your first example.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error because you are accessing `this.respond`. But `log` (and `respond`) is not an object method anymore, so `this` doesn't refer to an object with a `respond` method. Instead you simply reference the function (`respond`) directly:

`this.respond(...)` becomes `respond(...)`

---

However, there is no reason to use `.bind` at all, not even in your ES5 solution (you are never using `this` inside `respond`).

All you have to do is call the function:

```
export default function log (req, res) {
  return respond(req, res, 400, 'no data received');
}
```

Comment: `(req, res, 400, 'no data received')` the params are too many. that's why I use `bind`

Comment: Uh? `respond` is defined as `function respond (req, res, status, message) {` It takes 4 arguments. I'm passing 4 arguments. Maybe my answer wasn't clear, let me add more code.

Comment: Yes `function respond (req, res, status, message) {` takes 4 params. I am trying to reduce the params in there too.

Comment: tbh, I prefer `return respond(req, res, 400, 'no data received');` becos it is clearer than using `bind`.